# How to endEditing on UIViewRepresentable in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, stripe-payments

I have a first responder `textField` but I want to be able to close the keyboard when the screen is tapped or when the user presses a button.

Here is my `UIViewRepresentable`:

```
public struct CustomSTPPaymentCardTextField: UIViewRepresentable {

@Binding var paymentMethodParams: STPPaymentMethodParams?
let background: Color = ColorManager.backgroundColor

public init(paymentMethodParams: Binding<STPPaymentMethodParams?>) {
    _paymentMethodParams = paymentMethodParams
    
    
}

public func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(parent: self)
}

public func makeUIView(context: Context) -> STPPaymentCardTextField {
    let paymentCardField = STPPaymentCardTextField()
    paymentCardField.borderColor = nil
    paymentCardField.borderWidth = 0

    paymentCardField.becomeFirstResponder()
   

    return paymentCardField
}


public func updateUIView(_ paymentCardField: STPPaymentCardTextField, context: Context) {
    
}

public class Coordinator: NSObject, STPPaymentCardTextFieldDelegate {
    var parent: CustomSTPPaymentCardTextField
    init(parent: CustomSTPPaymentCardTextField) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

}
```

}

Here is how I called it in the view:

```
CustomSTPPaymentCardTextField(paymentMethodParams: $paymentMethodParams)
```

I've tried to pass a binding boolean to activate `endEditing`

I've also tried to use the following function:

```
#if canImport(UIKit)
extension View {
    func hideKeyboard() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
#endif
```

I've also tried the following:

```
UIApplication.shared.resignFirstResponder()
```

I've tried all of the above methods with and without `DispatchQueue.main.async` but none of them seem to work.

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: You posted a lot of app-specific code in the question, can you edit it in order to have a [mcve]?

Comment: @Cristik Done. Please have a look now and let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost correct with the `extension` on `View`

Use `endEditing` on all the windows. That can be called from anywhere.

```
extension View {
  static func endEditing() {
    UIApplication.shared.windows.forEach { $0.endEditing(false) }
  }
}
```

That approach might not be correct if you had a multi-scene app.

Answer (score 0):

Add an action to any button or in viewWillDisappear method inside UIViewController class

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

add this line. This will dismiss keyboard and stops editing.

Comment: My view is a SwiftUI view

Answer (score 0):

It Worked fine for me.

```
#if canImport(UIKit)
extension View {
    func hideKeyboard() {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}
#endif
```